# duplicate value when showing image in costume gridview

Tags: java, android

Im having a hard time  to figure it out why my image are showing duplicate in my costume grid (staggeredgridview)

the progam using lazy method to fetch image from webservice and insert into db , if user access the program without internet or accesss the old image data will be fetch from local db instead.

here is my main class :

```
private int index;
private Mysecondworker msw;
private main activity;
private String value;
private int filter = 0;
private boolean isLoading = false;
private int Sort = 0;
private StaggeredGridView mystaggerdgridview ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mystaggerdgridview = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    mystaggerdgridview.setColumnCount(2);
    activity = this;
    loadingisactive(true);
    msw = new Mysecondworker(activity, value, String.valueOf(index++), 0,0);
    msw.execute();

    mystaggerdgridview .setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(ViewGroup view, int scrollState) {

        public void onScroll(ViewGroup view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean needtofetchMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount  >= totalItemCount ;
            if (needtofetchMore && !loadingisactive){
                loadingisactive= true;
                hw = new Mysecondworker(activity, value, String.valueOf(index++), filter,Sort);
                hw.execute();
            }

        }
    });
}
    private Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } finally {

            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return t;
}
public void setloadingisactive(boolean flag){
    loadingisactive= flag;
}
```

and my Mysecondworker class :

```
public class Mysecondworker 
        extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> {


    private main  targetCtx;
    private String Mysecondworker_key;
    myAdapter myadapter;
    private LinearLayout Mysecondworker_progress;
    private String Mysecondworker_index , Mysecondworker_sort;
    private int Mysecondworker_filter = 0;
    private LinearLayout Mysecondworker_pagination;
    private ImageView Mysecondworker_imgPagination;
    private AnimationDrawable Mysecondworker_frameAnimation;
    private String Mysecondworker_lastID = "0";
    private StaggeredGridView mystaggerdgridview ;

    public Mysecondworker(main mycontext, String mykey, String myindex, int myfilter,int mysort) {
        this.targetCtx = mycontext;
        Mysecondworker_key = mykey;
        mystaggerdgridview = (StaggeredGridView) targetCtx.findViewById(id.grid);
        Mysecondworker_index = myindex;
        Mysecondworker_filter = myfilter;
        Mysecondworker_sort = String.valueOf(mysort);
        Mysecondworker_pagination = (LinearLayout) targetCtx.findViewById(id.pagination_load);
        Mysecondworker_imgPagination = (ImageView) targetCtx
                .findViewById(id.loadingpaginganimation);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = (LinearLayout) targetCtx.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        if (Integer.parseInt(index) == 0)
            Mysecondworker_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Mysecondworker_pagination.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Mysecondworker_imgPagination.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loadanimation);
        Mysecondworker_frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) Mysecondworker_imgPagination.getBackground();
        Mysecondworker_frameAnimation.start();

        //finding the last id of images
        myAdapter mAd = (myAdapter) mystaggerdgridview.getAdapter();
        if (mAd != null && mAd.getCount() > 0) {
            lastID = mAd.getData().get(mAd.getCount() - 1).get("id");
        }else
            lastID = "0";



    }

    @Override
    protected AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... param) {

        try {
            String xml = [[[getting image from web service with  unique id for each one]]]
            SaxXmlParser mygalleryparser = new SaxXmlParser(xml, "imagegallery");
            mygalleryparser.runParser();

            if (Integer.parseInt(Mysecondworker_index) == 0 && Integer.parseInt(Mysecondworker_key) > 0) {
                table_imagegallery obj_imagegallery = new table_imagegallery();
                obj_imagegallery.subjectId = Integer.parseInt(Mysecondworker_key);
                obj_imagegallery.DeleteBySubjectId();
            }

            for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : mygalleryparser.getParsedData()) {
                table_imagegallery imagegallery = new table_imagegallery();
                imagegallery.id = Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("id"));

                if (Integer.parseInt(key) < 1) {
                    imagegallery.Delete();
                }
                imagegallery.imgageurl = hashMap.get("imageurlfromxml");

                imagegallery.Insert();
            }
            AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> myresult = new AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(
                    mygalleryparser.getParsedData());
            return myresult;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myresult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            table_imagegallery forofflinefetch = new table_imagegallery();
            List<table_imagegallery> Off_imagegallery = new ArrayList<table_imagegallery>();

            switch (Integer.parseInt(Mysecondworker_key)) {
            case -1:
                if (Integer.parseInt(Mysecondworker_index) == 0)
                    Off_imagegallery = forofflinefetch.GetAllImages();
                break;
            }

            for (table_imagegallery imagegallery : Off_imagegallery) {
                HashMap<String, String> mapforimage = new HashMap<String, String>();
                mapforimage.put("id", String.valueOf(imagegallery.id));
                mapforimage.put("thumb_url1", imagegallery.imgageurl);
                myresult.add(mapforimage);
            }
            AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> myresultReturn = new AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(
                    myresult , true);
            return myresultReturn;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(
            AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> myresult) {

        Mysecondworker_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Mysecondworker_frameAnimation.stop();
        Mysecondworker_pagination.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (myresult.getError() != null) {

                //[[[errorr apear here]]]];
        } else {

            myAdapter mAd = (myAdapter) mystaggerdgridview.getAdapter();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> outputResult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            if (mAd != null && mAd.getCount() > 0) {

                outputResult = mAd.getData();

            }
            outputResult.addAll(myresult.getResult());
            if (mAd == null) {
                myadapter = new myAdapter(targetCtx, outputResult);
                mystaggerdgridview.setAdapter(myadapter);
            } else {
                mAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (!myresult.checkforofline())
                targetCtx.setloadingisactive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my async class :

```
public class AsyncTaskResult<T> {
    private T myresult = null;
    private Exception error = null;
    private boolean _checkforofline = false;

    public T getResult() {
        return myresult;
    }

    public Exception getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(T myresult) {
        super();
        this.myresult = myresult;
    }
    public AsyncTaskResult(T myresult,boolean isOffline) {
        super();
        this.myresult = myresult;
        _checkforofline = checkforofline;
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult() {
        super();
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(Exception error) {
        super();
        this.error = error;
    }

    public boolean checkforofline() {
        return _checkforofline;
    }
```

and madapter class :

```
   public myAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listhast) {
        myactivity = act;
        mydata=listhast;
        myinflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        myimageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext(),true);
    }

        private Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mydata.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getData(){
        return mydata;
    }
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {

                final myviewholder viewHolder;
                final HashMap<String, String> my_data_base_on_position = mydata.get(position);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    if(Integer.parseInt(my_data_base_on_position.get("id")) % 2 == 1){
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutright, parent, false);
                        }else{
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutleft, parent, false);
                        }
                    viewHolder = new myviewholder();
                    viewHolder.tv0 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textid);
                    viewHolder.imageurl = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

                }else{
                    viewHolder = (myviewholder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                LayoutParams lp;
                if(data.size() > 0 ){

                    viewHolder.tv0.setText(my_data_base_on_position.get("id"));
                    viewHolder.tv0.setTag(my_data_base_on_position.get("id"));
                classtoloadimagefromurl.DisplayImage(my_data_base_on_position.get("imageurl"), viewHolder.imageurl);

                        lp = new LayoutParams(convertView.getLayoutParams());
                        lp.span = 1;

                        convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);

                return convertView;
                }else{
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.noimage, parent, false);
                    lp = new LayoutParams(convertView.getLayoutParams());
                    lp.span = 1;
                    convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    return convertView;
                }

            }
```

intresting if i use listview instead of staggeredgrid in my madapter class everything goes fine but if i choose to show item in uneven ui , dupplicate value apears when it try to fetch !

this is the error :

```
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557): Error inserting imagegallery
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1584)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1428)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at com.imagegallery.Tabel_for_images.Insert(Tabel_for_images.java:109)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at com.imagegallery.Mysecondworker.doInBackground(Mysecondworker.java:141)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at com.imagegallery.Mysecondworker.doInBackground(Mysecondworker.java:1)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-09 11:51:52.656: E/Database(29557):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```